# FluentD Output in Plain Text (non-json) format

Tags: fluentd

I'm new to FluentD and I'm trying to determine if we can replace our current syslog application with FluentD. The issue that I'm trying to solve is compatability between FluentD and Legacy Application (which works w/ rsyslog) but cannot handle json.

Can FluentD output data in the format that it receives it - plain text (non-json) format that is RFC5424 compliant ?
From my research on the topic, the output is always json. I've explored using the `single_value` option, but that just extracts the `message` component which is incomplete without the `host`.

Any inputs or suggestions are welcome.

Here is the Fluentd config

```
##########
# INPUTS #
##########
# udp syslog
<source>
  @type syslog
  <transport udp>
  </transport>
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 514
  tag syslog
  <parse>
    message_format auto
    with_priority true
  </parse>
</source>

###########
# OUTPUTS #
###########
<match syslog**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/syslog
    compress gzip
  </store>
  <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/rfc_syslog
    compress gzip
    <format>
      @type single_value
      message_key message
    </format>
  </store>
</match>
```

Based on the configuration above, I receive the following outputs
File Output from the `syslog` location - which is all JSON

```
2022-10-21T09:34:53-05:00       syslog.user.info        {"host":"icw-pc01.lab","ident":"MSWinEventLog\t2\tSystem\t136\tFri","message":"34:52 2022\t7036\tService Control Manager\tN/A\tN/A\tInformation\ticw-pc01.lab\tNone\t\tThe AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC) service entered the running state.\t6 "}
```

File Output from the `rfc_syslog` location - which contains the message_key message single value

```
34:52 2022      7036    Service Control Manager N/A     N/A     Information     icw-pc01.lab    None            The AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC) service entered the running state.     6
```

Desired Output that we'd like (to support our legacy apps and legacy integrations)

```
Oct 21 09:34:53 icw-pc01.lab MSWinEventLog      2       System  136     Fri Oct 21 09:34:52 2022        7036    Service Control Manager N/A     N/A     Information icw-pc01.lab     None            The AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC) service entered the running state.        6
```

Update:
The suggestion below solved the parsing as desired. However, when I try to forward the data to a remote syslog server, it is still going out as JSON. Below is the revised fluentd config

```
##########
# INPUTS #
##########
# udp syslog
<source>
  @type syslog
  <transport udp>
  </transport>
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 514
  tag syslog
  <parse>
    @type none
    message_format auto
    with_priority true
  </parse>
</source>

###########
# OUTPUTS #
###########
<match syslog**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/syslog
    compress gzip
  </store>
  <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/rfc_syslog
    compress gzip
    <format>
      @type single_value
      message_key message
    </format>
    tag rfc_syslog
  </store>
  <store>
     @type forward
     <server>
       host 192.168.0.2
       port 514
     </server>
  </store>
</match>

<match rfc_syslog**>
  @type forward
  <server>
     host 192.168.0.3
     port 514
  </server>
</match>
```

When configured as above, there is no forwarding happening on the 192.168.0.3 (my guess is the `tag` is not getting applied).
As far as the forwarding for 192.168.0.2 goes, I see the messages in the Kiwi Syslog Server - but they are in json (which is what I was trying to avoid for my legacy app).
Here is the output on the Kiwi Syslog App: [kiwi-syslog-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlGMg.png)

Update 2 [11/11/2022] : After applying the suggested config

```
2022-11-11 09:36:59 -0600 [info]: Received graceful stop
2022-11-11 09:36:59 -0600 [info]: Received graceful stop
2022-11-11 09:36:59 -0600 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now stopping worker=0
2022-11-11 09:36:59 -0600 [info]: #0 shutting down fluentd worker worker=0
2022-11-11 09:36:59 -0600 [info]: #0 shutting down input plugin type=:syslog plugin_id="object:7e4"
2022-11-11 09:36:59 -0600 [info]: #0 shutting down output plugin type=:copy plugin_id="object:780"
2022-11-11 09:36:59 -0600 [info]: #0 shutting down output plugin type=:stdout plugin_id="object:7bc"
2022-11-11 09:37:15 -0600 [info]: #0 shutting down output plugin type=:forward plugin_id="object:794"
2022-11-11 09:37:16 -0600 [info]: Worker 0 finished with status 0
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '5.1.4'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-flowcounter-simple' version '0.1.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kafka' version '0.17.3'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser' version '1.0.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.2'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus_pushgateway' version '0.1.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-remote_syslog' version '1.1.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.4.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '1.6.1'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-sd-dns' version '0.1.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-splunk-hec' version '1.2.10'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-syslog_rfc5424' version '0.8.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.5'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '1.1.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-utmpx' version '0.5.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '1.5.0'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.14.4'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.14.3'
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: adding forwarding server '192.168.0.2:514' host="192.168.0.2" port=514 weight=60 plugin_id="object:794"
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <system>
    process_name "aggregator1"
  </system>
  <source>
    @type syslog
    bind "0.0.0.0"
    port 514
    tag "syslog"
    <transport udp>
    </transport>
    <parse>
      @type "none"
      message_format auto
      with_priority true
    </parse>
  </source>
  <match syslog**>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type "forward"
      <server>
        host "192.168.0.2"
        port 514
      </server>
    </store>
    <store>
      @type "stdout"
    </store>
  </match>
</ROOT>
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: starting fluentd-1.14.4 pid=25424 ruby="2.7.5"
2022-11-11 09:49:03 -0600 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/opt/td-agent/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/opt/td-agent/bin/fluentd", "--log", "/var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log", "--daemon", "/var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid", "--under-supervisor"]
2022-11-11 09:49:04 -0600 [info]: adding match pattern="syslog**" type="copy"
2022-11-11 09:49:04 -0600 [info]: #0 adding forwarding server '192.168.0.2:514' host="192.168.0.2" port=514 weight=60 plugin_id="object:794"
2022-11-11 09:49:04 -0600 [info]: adding source type="syslog"
2022-11-11 09:49:04 -0600 [warn]: parameter 'message_format' in <parse>
  @type "none"
  message_format auto
  with_priority true
</parse> is not used.
2022-11-11 09:49:04 -0600 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=25440 ppid=25437 worker=0
2022-11-11 09:49:04 -0600 [info]: #0 listening syslog socket on 0.0.0.0:514 with udp
2022-11-11 09:49:04 -0600 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2022-11-11 09:49:04.682972925 -0600 syslog.auth.notice: {"message":"date=2022-11-11 time=15:49:04 devname=\"fg101.lab.local\" devid=\"FG101\" logid=\"0000000013\" type=\"traffic\" subtype=\"forward\" level=\"notice\" vd=\"vdom1\" eventtime=1668181744 srcip=10.1.100.155 srcport=40772 srcintf=\"port12\" srcintfrole=\"undefined\" dstip=35.197.51.42 dstport=443 dstintf=\"port11\" dstintfrole=\"undefined\" poluuid=\"707a0d88-c972-51e7-bbc7-4d421660557b\" sessionid=8058 proto=6 action=\"close\" policyid=1 policytype=\"policy\" policymode=\"learn\" service=\"HTTPS\" dstcountry=\"United States\" srccountry=\"Reserved\" trandisp=\"snat\" transip=172.16.200.2 transport=40772 duration=180 sentbyte=82 rcvdbyte=151 sentpkt=1 rcvdpkt=1 appcat=\"unscanned\""}
2022-11-11 09:49:04.683460611 -0600 syslog.local4.debug: {"message":"2022-11-11T15:49:04.407Z esx01.lab.local Rhttpproxy: verbose rhttpproxy[1051289] [Originator@6876 sub=Proxy Req 87086] Resolved endpoint : [N7Vmacore4Http16LocalServiceSpecE:0x000000fa0ed298d0] _serverNamespace = /sdk action = Allow _port = 8307"}
2022-11-11 09:49:04.683737270 -0600 syslog.local4.debug: {"message":"2022-11-11T15:49:04.408Z esx01.lab.local Rhttpproxy: verbose rhttpproxy[1051277] [Originator@6876 sub=Proxy Req 87086] Connected to localhost:8307 (/sdk) over <io_obj p:0x000000f9cc153648, h:18, <TCP '127.0.0.1 : 59272'>, <TCP '127.0.0.1 : 8307'>>"}
2022-11-11 09:49:04.683950628 -0600 syslog.local4.debug: {"message":"2022-11-11T15:49:04.410Z esx01.lab.local Rhttpproxy: verbose rhttpproxy[1082351] [Originator@6876 sub=Proxy Req 87086] The client closed the stream, not unexpectedly."}
2022-11-11 09:49:04.684235085 -0600 syslog.local4.debug: {"message":"2022-11-11T15:49:04.422Z esx01.lab.local Rhttpproxy: verbose rhttpproxy[1051291] [Originator@6876 sub=Proxy Req 87087] New proxy client <SSL(<io_obj p:0x000000fa0ea0bff8, h:17, <TCP '10.1.233.128 : 443'>, <TCP '10.0.0.250 : 46140'>>)>"}
2022-11-11 09:49:04.684453505 -0600 syslog.local4.debug: {"message":"2022-11-11T15:49:04.423Z esx01.lab.local Rhttpproxy: verbose rhttpproxy[1287838] [Originator@6876 sub=Proxy Req 87087] Resolved endpoint : [N7Vmacore4Http16LocalServiceSpecE:0x000000fa0ed298d0] _serverNamespace = /sdk action = Allow _port = 8307"}
2022-11-11 09:49:04.684749571 -0600 syslog.local4.debug: {"message":"2022-11-11T15:49:04.423Z esx01.lab.local Rhttpproxy: verbose rhttpproxy[1051278] [Originator@6876 sub=Proxy Req 87087] Connected to localhost:8307 (/sdk) over <io_obj p:0x000000f9cc153648, h:18, <TCP '127.0.0.1 : 51121'>, <TCP '127.0.0.1 : 8307'>>"}
2022-11-11 09:49:10.521901882 -0600 syslog.auth.info: {"message":"Nov 11 09:49:10 icw-pc01.lab MSWinEventLog\t2\tSecurity\t744984\tFri Nov 11 09:49:10 2022\t6417\tMicrosoft-Windows-Security-Auditing\tN/A\tN/A\tSuccess Audit\ticw-pc01.lab\tSystem Integrity\t\tThe FIPS mode crypto selftests succeeded.     Process ID:  0x17cc   Process Name:  C:\\Python27\\python.exe\t717211 "}
```

Comment: Please add the input and output messages to your question highlighting your use-case.

Comment: [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) is for `syslog`. Have you looked at https://docs.fluentd.org/input/syslog?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Azeem - Thanks for your feedback. I've updated my problem statement and provided the config, output and desired output.

Comment: @js342: Thank you! Did you try to use https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/none?

Comment: @Azeem - Thank you, this appears to get me the desired output in the file. This answers my question. 
I've a follow up - when I try to `forward` the logs in the rfc_syslog location (in a subsequent `match` block) to my remote syslog server, the forward appears to be going out as json. I also used Kiwi Syslog Server to confirm the behavior. I've even explored using the syslog_rfc5424 / remote_syslog plugins in vain. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @js342: That's good! Please edit your question and add the abovementioned scenario at the end with all the relevant details. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem - updated the question w/ the `Update` section.

Comment: @js342: Regarding the events not being forwarded to `192.168.0.3`, you might need to fix the `match` section. See https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#note-on-match-order. It looks like there are some config issues. You must be getting config errors/warnings in the `fluentd`'s startup logs. Please add those as well.

Comment: @js342: For debugging, you might want to dump the logs in the `match` section to a local file or to `STDOUT`. The `forward` plugin should be forwarding the same output to Kiwi Syslog Server. You can debug and adjust logs accordingly.

Comment: @Azeem - I tried the suggestions and I'm not seeing anything in the logs that indicate something is wrong. I'm still seeing the same results as in my screenshot. I was able to get some data to show up via trial and error (I'll update that in my question shortly). Upon digging a some more and combing through captures, it appears the `forward` plugin is using `msgpack` to ship the data to my remote syslog and I think that is where it breaks the formatting (in my limited understanding).

Comment: @js342: `fluentd` converts events to `msgpack` format to communicate with other components internally. From your above configuration, I'm not seeing any such configuration for the output. I'm not sure why the output is in the `msgpack` format. Please try this config https://godbolt.org/z/cdb7cczPM and observe the output in the `fluentd` logs.

Comment: @Azeem - please find attached the logs (under update2 above in the main question). As shown in the logs, the message json object is what is being forwarded onwards - with the "message" key word and the extra characters that go w/ the json structure. 
The message key word and the extra characters being shipped is - what breaks the legacy app (since it can't handle json objects - hence the original request).

Comment: @js342: From the logs, it's clear that the logs are properly being fetched and printed on STDOUT. Please use this config https://godbolt.org/z/7nG4Wdrx1 with the [remote_syslog](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-remote_syslog) output plugin configured. Fix any issues in the confg if there are any. I just put config together from its page. Let's see how it works for your setup.

Comment: @Azeem - Thanks for the feedback. In all my previous attempts, the logs were always coming in as desired and stored in the files as desired. 
With regards to the plugins, I've tried the following plugins:
a) fluent-plugin-remote_syslog [Didn't work - constant restarts of the td-agent]
b) fluent-plugin-remote-syslog [Worked - but output not as desired]
c) fluent-plugin-syslog_rfc5424 [Worked - but output not as desired]

I'll probably rebuild my sandbox environment and try installing these suggestions again. I'll investigate the remote_syslog plugin & I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @js342: Sure, please do. If you could put all the configurations in a small reproducible example via GitHub, that'd be helpful to understand your complete end-to-end scenario. Maybe, with docker and docker-compose if you have experience with that. It'll be easier for me to reproduce and experiment with it on my side too. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @Azeem. I was able to get the remote syslog plugin to work on a sandbox environment. After rebuilding my original environment, I was able to  get it to work as well - I was missing some dependencies (my VM is not on the internet so can't do a quick update). I've a new issue - I think since the events are forwarded to a "Remote Syslog" - it appends a new timestamp/hostname/tag to the "actual event". I've attached the files on github over here [link](https://github.com/jtsmith342/test) 
If you have any suggestions on how to drop the extra elements, it would help.

Comment: @js342: Good to hear that you were able to make it work! You might want to self-answer this question to complete it. As for the appended fields, from the description, it looks like you may alter the events with the `record_transformer` or `record_modifier` filter plugins to fix those. But, why those were being appended, the root cause needs to be looked at on the source side.

Comment: @Azeem - thanks for the feedback. With regards to (those) appended fields, it appears to be part of the remote_syslog plugin so I'm unsure how the record_transformer / record_modifier would work.

Comment: @js342: No problem. That sounds like the destination server is adding its own metadata to the events. I may not be able to offer any advice here. I haven't had any such experience. You might want to see the configuration of the destination `remote_syslog` (looks like there's no such option there). You can open an [issue](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-remote_syslog/issues/new/choose) to propose such a feature.

Comment: @js342: Alternatively, you may add a local instance of `fluentd` to receive events from the source machine and then alter them before feeding into the local syslog server.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my response above (on Nov 29, 2022) - I was missing some dependencies for the Remote Syslog plugin.
Once the dependencies were installed, I was able to get the Remote Syslog plugin to work as desired (w/ the extra text as outlined in my comment above).